# Single oauth token and secret to access multiple services from google

Tags: oauth, google-api

I am using oauth to access different services provided by google.I am able to generate token per service basis. But I want to generate single token to use multiple services from google.
Can anyone tell me the solution for this?

Answer (score 7):

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2

As per the Google OAuth2 docs, it is possible to do this by setting multiple scopes, but be warned, it isn't a happy experience.

When making your request, set the scope parameter to multiple scopes, each separated by a single space.

Example: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.google.com/m8/feeds"

You can currently find a list of scopes here: https://developers.google.com/gdata/faq

Unfortunately, API access is not additive, meaning, if you ask for an access token for the Google Contacts API, then later on *as the same application* ask for an access token for the Google Profile API, you will end up with two access tokens, and neither can be used to access the other API.  Facebook at least has the decency to give you back a single access token that grants access to all the permissions granted so far.

Because of this, you are left having to keep track of multiple access tokens (a horrible nightmare, given they expire very quickly), or ask for all of your permissions up-front, which is a user experience disaster.

Fragmented and disparate, the Google APIs are currently setup to fail if you want to do tight, multi-faceted integration.

Comment: This might be a late response, but could clarify what some of the issues are with multiple scopes are? I use multiple scopes routinely and haven't found any issues with it.

Is the issue purely the one about scope grants not being additive? You can always ping https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo to see what scopes a token has and then add your new scope to it. Simple enough workaround. However, in general its simplest and easiest to request all scopes ahead of time so that its easier for you as a developer and cleaner for the end user.

Comment: Avoid "one size fits all" tokens. The recommended best practice to help the user understand the process and increase the likelihood that they will approve your request for access is to use the least number of scopes as possible at the time when the access is needed. So in contrast to arun, you should use discrete tokens for each point in time the grant is done. In my experience this hasn't resulted in a 'nightmare' to manage. You should store your refresh tokens keyed by user and api scope so that you know which to use in which situation. The library should take care of getting access tokens.

Comment: When you compare that to Facebook's API, for example, which allows you to request additional scopes later on, returning a single token which grants the entirety of scopes granted by the user over time, I find it hard to believe that you consider the handling of multiple tokens to be superior.  I hope it's clear from the text that "one size fits all" tokens are bad, but I do think that when you ask for more permissions "just in time" later on, you shouldn't be penalised by having to handle multiple tokens. Glad it wasn't a nightmare for you though; perhaps I should add "YMMV" :)

Comment: This might have been true in 2012, but since the last few years Google has added incremental scopes which allow you to collect additional permissions at the time of need. The new access token that is generated has all the scopes from the previous increments as well. Read more - https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes#incrementalAuth